# Парсер на python не читает информацию с сайта, а выдает None

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Делаю парсер на питоне для сайта: https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/

Задача забрать жанры фильма из фильмов (на странице отображается как: 'span', class_='selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item')

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.1 (Windows NT 7.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0',
           'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

def get_html(url, params = ''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('span', class_='selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(
            {
                'title': item.find('span', class_='title')
            }
        )
    return cards


html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Не могу понять почему выдает результат: [{'title': None}, {'title': None}, {'title': None},... {'title': None}]

Comment: Выдает тактие результаты, потому что нет span-ов одновременно с классами 'selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item' и 'title'. Я попробовал прогнать код - ни у одного спана нет класса 'title'.

Comment: @Alex Спасибо! Получилось!